# INSERT.... ON  DUPLICATE KEY при условии, что повторяются только два поля

Tags: mysql

Скажите как применить INSERT.... ON  DUPLICATE KEY, если у меня совпадают только два поля?
Например, если в таблице существуют такие записи:

```
p1  |  p2  |  p2  |  p3
-----------------------
 1      2      3      4
```

И при добавлении новой записи, если p1 и p2 совпадают, то обновить p3 и p4.
Ни одно поле не является уникальным - это условие.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @alexlz комбинация, кстати, уникальная... спасибо за наводку... Сделайте ваш комент ответом...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А комбинация p1 и p2 является уникальной? Если да -- то объявите уникальный ключ/индекс по колонкам p1,p2 (если нет, то встаёт вопрос -- где обновлять p3 и p4)

Comment: Так и сделал, заработало...

Comment: а как объявить уникальный ключ/индекс по колонкам?

Answer (score 2):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` работает только при наличии `UNIQUE` или `PRIMARY KEY`. Это указано в [официальной документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: ну я в курсе...

Comment: ок. Ответ на ваш вопрос: никак. Необходимо использовать несколько запросов. Если 
    `UPDATE .... WHERE `p1` = 'value' AND `p2` = 'value' 
неудачен, использовать `INSERT`

Comment: Ага...спасибо.